# AlwaysOn Availability Group Forced Failover

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, failover

May I request your input.

I setup SQL 2012 with always on availability group for my databases in sync and secondary readable mode. I completed failover tests with sync mode and it is functioning as expected.

After a forced failover testing with async mode, do I need to rebuild my old primary database? Because changes in the new primary are not reflected back. The database status is not synchronized...instead of synchronizing...

Appreciate your input as I get my head around this concept.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> After a forced failover testing with async mode, do I need to rebuild my old primary database?

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "rebuild" the database, but provided the databases are still in a working condition then you shouldn't need to take any actions like that.

What you're seeing, by performing a forced failover, is by design.  If you do a forced failover, you could potentially have failed over to a replica that isn't completely caught up or at the same point-in-time as the primary replica.  Because of that, data movement is suspended to the secondary replica(s) from the now primary replica so there is a way to have manual intervention if you are now on a database that is "behind".  That behavior that you are seeing is a good thing.

[This BOL reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877957.aspx#FollowUp) explains it all:

> **After a forced failover, all secondary databases are suspended**. This includes the former primary databases, after the former primary replica comes back online and discovers that it is now a secondary replica. **You must manually resume each suspended database individually on each secondary replica**.
>
> When a secondary database is resumed, it initiates data synchronization with the corresponding primary database. **The secondary database rolls back any log records that were never committed on the new primary database**. Therefore, if you are concerned about possible data loss on the post-failover primary databases, you should attempt to create a database snapshot on the suspended databases on one of the synchronous-commit secondary databases.

Please see [this BOL reference on how to resume an AG database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877956.aspx).

The T-SQL for this would be:

```
alter database YourDatabaseName
set hadr resume;
```

***NOTE/WARNING/DISCLAIMER: You really need to do some leg work to ensure that you are not causing data loss by resuming data movement.  See above, it could be a huge problem.  The point of suspending data movement is for this very reason:  To manually make sure you can recover as much data as possible.  When you resume data movement, that could be irreversible.  When you resume data movement after a forced failover, you have to have the words "potential data loss" in the forefront of your mind always.***

Comment: Hi Thomas Thank you for the response. Please can you break this one step further for me. This is a test and there are no txns since the failover. When it shows as not synchronized. What do I need to do to resume the database.Do I need to delete the availability group? I do not see the suspended state...

Comment: For the availability group I am only able to remove the active primary db not the secondary - remove gets greyed out. do I delete the availability group resume the db and then recreate the availability group?

Comment: @TDPSQL_Newbie See my edit.  And definitely follow the "note/warning/disclaimer".

Comment: Many thanks Thomas, used this link. Appreciate your input.

Comment: @TDPSQL_Newbie No problem!  Always glad to help.